# Check previous build information in VSTS (VSTS API)

Tags: version-control, azure-devops

Are previous build variables accessible during execution of a VSTS build? For example, can I get $(Build.SourceVersion) or $(Build.QueuedBy) of the previous build?

I can get current build information through the build variables like $(Build.SourceVersion) but can I get something like $(Build.Previous.SourceVersion)?

Comment: No. What are you trying to accomplish with that information?

Comment: Comparing the source version of the last successful build to the most recent build

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: If a change has been made to a git repo since the last time it was successfully built, set a variable (and only run one step if the variable isn't set)

Comment: Again, for what purpose? I'm trying to figure out what problem you're trying to solve in order to suggest an alternate solution.

Comment: Redeploying a live database causes a spike in request time, so I want to not deploy the database unless there have been changes. The database is in the same release as the web app and I don't want the database to deploy if there haven't been changes.

Comment: What do you think of get previous build through REST API?

Answer (score 0):

There aren’t the built-in variables for previous build information, the workaround is that you can call [Builds REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds) (can be filter status, such as completed, inProgress) through PowerShell during this build. (The first item of the result is the newest one)

```
$base64authinfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $User, $Password)))
$responseFromGet = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64authinfo)}
```

Some articles about calling REST API: [Calling VSTS APIs with PowerShell](http://blog.devmatter.com/calling-vsts-apis-with-powershell/), [VSTS/TFS REST API: The basics and working with builds and releases](http://blog.nwcadence.com/vststfs-rest-api-the-basics-and-working-with-builds-and-releases/)

You can use value of `System.AccessToken` variable as password (Check **Allow scripts to access OAuth token option** in Options tab) and username can be anything.

Comment: I'm looking through the REST API but having a bit of difficulty. I have $uri = "$vstsAccount" + "DefaultCollection/$projectName/_apis/build/builds/" + "$buildId" + "?api-version=2.0" and I'm running a GET on it but the data it returns is different from in the example.

Comment: @user3364161 What's the different?

Answer (score -1):

No. "Previous" is a nebulous concept when you're talking about things that can run in parallel. What if you have 3 builds running concurrently?

Comment: It's for a continuous integration project. When someone checks in new code that triggers a build; I want to compare the repo from the last successful build to the build that was just triggered.