# Access "Difference in work items" in release stage

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to generate release notes from work items in Azure DevOps.

In the Release Pipelines Web Interface there is a list of changed work items since the last deployment under *Work Items / Difference in Work Items*.

Is there a way to access this list during the Release Job via REST API or a Release Variable?

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46334916/2779990).  It may lead you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

Use the [Build API - Get Work Items Between Builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20work%20items%20between%20builds?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) method.

#### For arguments:

- `fromBuildId={fromBuildId}`

  - [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) the top successful build that is retained by release
- `toBuildId={toBuildId}`

  - use the `build_buildid` environment variable on the release agent

#### Original

I believe you'll use the [Builds API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20work%20items%20refs?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) for work items referenced on the build used in the release.

Your release should have a variable `[BUILD_BUILDID] --> [###]` that you can use to provide to the build API linked above.

When looking at the logs of a release pipeline, you can see the environment variables available to the pipeline by opening the **Initialize job** log.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately `BUILD_BUILDID` only gives me the current build. To get all changes between releases I would also need the build id of the previous deployment.

Comment: That was a misunderstanding on my part. I've made an edit that should address what you want.